Подробности работы система безопасности вк, яндекс почты, гугл почты?
На моем проекте если посмотреть в запросы через инструменты разработчика и найти запрос на получение данных, после чего скопировать его как фетч и вставить в консоль, то запрос вернет данные.
На таких проектах как вк, яндекс почта, гугл почта если проделать то же самое, то запрос ничего не вернет, есть предположение, что так работает одна из систем безопасности, подскажите название или ссылку где можно про это почитать, пожалуйста.

csrf токен наверное. Любой запрос срабатывает только один раз
